# DocumentDb: can multiple joins include empty sets

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a 'Message' collection in DocumentDb:

```js
{
  Subject: "Foo",
  To: [
    { "Name": "Me", "Address": "me@company.com" }
  ],
  Cc: [
    { "Name": "You", "Address": "you@company.com" }
  ]
}
```

and

```js
{
  Subject: "Bar",
  To: [
    { "Name": "You", "Address": "you@company.com" }
  ],
  Cc: []
}
```

I would like to select all documents that have 'you@company.com' as the To or Cc address:

```sql
SELECT Message.Subject
FROM Message
  JOIN To IN Message.To
  JOIN Cc IN Message.Cc
WHERE "you@company.com" IN (To.Address, Cc.Address)
```

This returns the first document, but not the second.

I believe the `JOIN Cc in Message.Cc` is causing the second document to be removed from the results because it is empty.

Is there a way I can structure the SQL query to include the second document in the result set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this require two queries (You could write it in one query using a user-defined function, but that approach might not be able to use the index effectively).

```
  SELECT Message.Subject
  FROM Message
  JOIN To IN Message.To
  WHERE To.Address = "you@company.com"

  SELECT Message.Subject
  FROM Message
  JOIN To IN Message.Cc
  WHERE Cc.Address = "you@company.com"
```

Alternatively, if you have values for both Name and Value, you could write it as:

```
SELECT Message.Subject
FROM Message
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(Message.To, { "Name": "You", "Address": "you@company.com" }) 
OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(Message.Cc, { "Name": "You", "Address": "you@company.com" })
```

If you'd like to see this added to DocumentDB's query, please support/upvote support for sub-queries at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/.

Comment: I have upvoted the subquery request.Is this a reasonable candidate for a stored procedure?

Comment: Thanks. Stored procedures have the same issue as UDFs, they would not be able to use the index. I would definitely recommend two queries - it's more lightweight, and you can even run them in parallel.